# Move branches without pushing them to the git repository?

Tags: git, github

I have a git repository and I have created several branches, each one of them has different non-finished work. I don't want to push them to the main repository unless it's strictly needed, because, as I said, it is a non-finished work.

Now I got a brand new laptop and I need to save/move that work to the new laptop. My ideas are as follow:

- push the branches to the main repository, which I repeat is the last path I would take if there is not other options
- copy all the `.git` folder and the current sources to the new laptop

Is there any other way? Would be enough to copy only the `.git` folder? Any workaround? How would you achieve this?

Comment: just use feature branches and check them out?

Comment: @NickVanderhoven how is that? I am not following you

Comment: you don't have to merge your work to your main branch, you can just keep your work on the feature branch, push it to the remote and check it out on your new laptop

Comment: @NickVanderhoven that's exactly what I said here `is the last path I would take if there is not other options` I am not the only one working in such repository and could be confused to others

Comment: I know, but I don't see why, if you use your own branches, you can remove them after the move too. However, you can always copy the repos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would be enough to copy only the .git folder?

Yes, it's enough. If you don't want to push changes to remote then just copy the Project folder with `.git`.

After Pasting the Project folder in your new laptop, you can checkout/play like normal clone repo.

```
$ git checkout <branch-name>
```

Comment: To checkout any branch in you new copied folder (in new laptop). @ReynierPM